# Using multiple data binding only displays [object Promise]

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

I need to compose the values from two data bindings in one text output.

Using just one binding as in the following example works perfectly fine:

**Working:**

```
<ObjectStatus 
  text="{
    path:'messages>type', 
    formatter: '.formatter.notificationMsg'}" 
  icon="{
    path: 'messages>type', 
    formatter: '.formatter.notificationIcon'
   }"
/>
```

However adding another binding leads to an output of "[object Promise]" for the second binding. The first one gets displayed correctly. I already set the binding mode to complex in bootstrap and tried things similar to the documentation https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/a2fe8e763014477e87990ff50657a0d0

**Not working:**

```
<ObjectStatus 
    text="{messages>user_id}{path: 'messages>type', 
           formatter: '.formatter.notificationMsg'}" 
    icon="{path: 'messages>type', 
           formatter: '.formatter.notificationIcon'}"/>
```

Does anyone have hint on how to put both parts together correctly? Let me know if you need more details!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how you write complex syntax binding :)

When you want to compose several expression bindings into you must enclose then in **{=** ... **}** (see https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/topic/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0)

But you will not be able to mix direct binding like *{messages>user_id}* with formatter bindings like *{path: 'messages>type', formatter: '.formatter.notificationMsg'}*, so this approach is not enough for you anyway ;)

So the correct approach would be to enhance your formatter so that it support a second parameter and then simply use it as follow:

```
<ObjectStatus
  text="{
    parts: [
      'messages>type',
      'messages>user_id'
    ],
    formatter: '.formatter.notificationMsg'
  }"
  ...
/>
```

Dont forget to modify the formatter accordingly:

```
notificationMsg(type, user_id) {
}
```